# How can I add an uncategorized barplot to the same chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to compare with the case where I do not categorize my data.

I can do

```
ggplot(dataset)+
    geom_boxplot(aes(x=Category, y=Values,fill = Category))
```

and I also can do

```
ggplot(dataset)+
    geom_boxplot(aes(y=Values))
```

But how can I display them combined in only one ggplot?

So x-axis would have labels like "Category A", "Category B", "Total".

Comment: Try `facet_grid`, also from the `ggplot2` library.

Comment: For a different style of solution using `facet_grid(..., margins=TRUE)`, try this: `ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_grid(. ~ Species, space="free", scales="free", margins=TRUE)`

Comment: By the way, the linked duplicate question does not specifically answer the OPs request "But how can I display them combined in only one ggplot?".